# Angular 5 set select object value manually

Tags: angular, forms, select, setvalue, angular-reactive-forms

I have one select, and I want to set an object value manually. I tried to use setValue or patchValue with Object, but it did not work.

```
<mat-select placeholder="Selecione a resposta" (change)="onSelectFraudResponse($event.value)" formControlName="response">
  <mat-option *ngFor="let res of fraudResponses" [value]="res">
    {{res.name}}
  </mat-option></mat-select>
```

I know is incorrect using template form and reactive form together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For binding objects you need to use `[ngValue]` since `[value]` is used for primitive types

**EDIT:**

Since i didn't see a concrete example how you can two-way bind an object inside `mat-select`, i would advise you use a property which will identify your object and instead of changing the whole object, you can just change that value, the right attribute for two-way databinding is `[(value)]`

Comment: Got it! But when I set [ngValue]
Can't bind to 'ngValue' since it isn't a known property of 'mat-select'.
Or I set incorrectly?
Sorry and thanks for help!

Comment: Seems like component `mat-select` doesn't provide access to that property, and from their docs it seems to me you can bind only primitive values to `mat-select` with two-way data binding, so you can't pass `object` to `[value]` but rather a string, i'll update my answer now